# AWS time traveling issues with dhclient

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, time, dhclient

I am a QA software engineer working on integration tests that require changes on the system clock to simulate the pass of the time. When running those tests on AWS EC2 instances I got unexpected behaviours that seem to be related to DHCP and DHCP client leases of IPs: the instance becomes unreachable and it is impossible to restore the connection to it.

I have read this post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=239374 where someone with a similar problem solved it by setting up a static IP address three years ago, but this solution doesn't seem to work for me. If I try to set up the static IP I end up with an unreachable host and there is no way to connect to it. I wonder if something has changed in the last three years that prevent me from the set that static IP.

I would like to ask for advice on this topic, what would you try and how?

I am considering using static IPs if I found a way to make them work or modify my network options to increase the lease time (or make it infinite), I accept any suggestion.

Best regards,

Comment: I wonder if the problem is ssh / https not liking the time being out. Have you tried using http?

Comment: Hello @Tim, and thank you for your answer! I have not tried HTTP because I don't have any web server running on those instances, the fact is that I need to run tests on them using Ansible through ssh and it is impossible. Yesterday I finally managed to set up static IP and the problem seems to end. I am not able yet to justify the error but I strongly think that it is related to dhclient.